# CSS Position: give space

Tags: css, css-position

JSFiddle Example code: http://jsfiddle.net/SUMPq/8/

I have some text on a container, the code is at the top of the HTML, near the body:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="title_content">
<h1>Heading TAG</h1><br />
<p>SOME TEXT<br />SOME TEXT<br /></p>
</div></div>
<div id="spacebox"></div>
```

Then with CSS positioning i display the content at other part of the page:

```
#container{position:relative;width:860px;height:0;}
#title_content{position:relative;top:100px;left:10%;font-size:14px;}
```

The problem is that the content of the h1 tag is dynamic and sometimes it can be only one line and sometimes two or more, and in these cases the space box can be too large or too small. How can i handle this spacebox to be dynamic in height depending on the text contained?

CSS space box

```
#spacebox{display:block;width:auto;height:100px;z-index:100;}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question exactly. can you elaborate ?
If you want dynamic height you can just give height:auto;

Answer (score 0):

just remove height:0; from #container
and give height:auto to #spacebox

Comment: The problem is if i do not put height:0px; then the text outside of the container overlaps. Check these examples, one with height:0 and other without: http://jsfiddle.net/kSqgs/24/ - http://jsfiddle.net/kSqgs/23/